# Need 5 Checkboxes that are sometimes dependent

Tags: excel, vba

This seems like it should be so simple, but all my forum searches have been fruitless.

What I'm trying to do is very simple:
I have five checkboxes that I want the user to be able to use. They need to be able to choose one, all, or any combination. For some reason I have not figured out how to make this work:

```
I14  J14
All  Y
1    Y
2    Y
3    Y
4    Y
5    Y
```

Here's what I have so far - can someone please help me figure out how to do the following?
1. If I click the checkbox for #1 (or 2, 3, 4, 5), write a value in the cell (currently containing "Y").
2. If I un-click the checkbox for #1 (or 2, 3, 4, 5), clear the value in the cell (or write a different one).
3. If I click the checkbox for All, write a value in that cell AND check all other boxes.
4. If I un-click the checkbox for All, clear the value in that cell AND un-check all other boxes.

```
Private Sub ChEmAll_Click()
    Range("J15").Value = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub ChEmELM_Click()
    Range("J16").Value = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub ChEmSFS_Click()
    Range("J17").Value = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub ChEmRNJ_Click()
    Range("J18").Value = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub ChEmATL_Click()
    Range("J19").Value = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub ChEmAUR_Click()
    Range("J20").Value = "Y"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with three checkboxes (CBox1, CBox2, and CBox3) on Sheet1 and in the code editor of that sheet here is what I have got:

```
Private Sub CBox1_Change() 'Check all checkboxes
    If CBox1.Value Then
        Me.Range("b1") = "Y"
    Else
        Me.Range("b1").ClearContents
    End If

    Dim CBox As OLEObject
    For Each CBox In Me.OLEObjects
        If InStr(LCase(CBox.progID), "checkbox") > 0 Then
            CBox.Object.Value = CBox1.Value
        End If
    Next CBox
End Sub

Private Sub CBox2_Change()
    If CBox1.Value Then
        Me.Range("b2") = "Y"
    Else
        Me.Range("b2").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CBox3_Change()
    If CBox1.Value Then
        Me.Range("b3") = "Y"
    Else
        Me.Range("b3").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

If you only have checkboxes as OleObjects in you worksheet you can skip the check "`If InStr(LCase(CBox.progID), "checkbox") > 0 Then`"